# How should I configure my Neural Network to accept a column of numpy.ndarrays as input?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a dataframe with 10k rows and the following columns:

```
      array                                     target
[1,5,6,1,3,etc...]                                5
[3,3,1,0,5,etc...]                                10
[0,0,1,1,7,etc...]                                3
        .                                         .
        .                                         .
        .                                         .
```

Each array has 33222 elements, so I have 10,000 rows each with a 33,222 long numpy.array that I want to input into a Neural Network to predict the target variable.

Here is how the NN is configured:

```
x = df.loc[:, 'array']
y = df.loc[:, 'target']

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy', 'mse', 'mae'])
                   
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

I'm getting

```
"ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays"
```

I haven't attempted to use arrays as input for a NN before, so I would also appreciate any advice on the optimal layer choice and configuration for this kind of problem.

Comment: Can you add x.shape and y.shape in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, I think the structure of your data is what's causing the problem. This line:

`x = df.loc[:, 'array']`

is returning the 'array' column, but each value in that column is another array, not a value. Instead try `x = np.matrix(df.loc[:, 'array'].tolist())`

Answer (score 1):

A small example on implementing neural network

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Generating random data
np.random.seed(100)
x = tf.constant(np.random.randint(50, size =(10000,33222)), dtype = tf.float32)
y = tf.constant(np.random.randint(50, size =(10000,)), dtype = tf.float32)
print(x.shape) # (10000, 33222)
print(y.shape) # (10000,)

def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(33222,)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy', 'mse', 'mae'])
    return model
model = create_model()

model.fit(x,y, epochs = 5)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
313/313 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 33659.8986 - accuracy: 0.0204 - mse: 33659.8986 - mae: 54.9263
Epoch 2/5
313/313 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 794.5642 - accuracy: 0.0198 - mse: 794.5642 - mae: 24.1756
Epoch 3/5
313/313 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 795.9055 - accuracy: 0.0196 - mse: 795.9055 - mae: 24.1960
Epoch 4/5
313/313 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 767.0253 - accuracy: 0.0201 - mse: 767.0253 - mae: 23.6541
Epoch 5/5
313/313 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 775.2028 - accuracy: 0.0196 - mse: 775.2028 - mae: 23.8585
```

Also, some things to remember:

1. Always use nonlinear activation functions for your hidden layers.ie(relu, elu etc)
2. The more layers you add, the more the model is able to learn complex features. However, your model can overfit and also take lot of time to train.
3. Increase your neurons and layers incrementally.
4. Use validation and test set to see the goodness of the model.
5. Use regularization to avoid overfitting of the model.

A note on dataset.

1. You should not use dataset which has this many features.
2. Use selective features from the dataset to avoid overfitting.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.